# passing data from a servlet to javascript code in an Ajax application?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a simple jsp/servlet application and I want to add AJAX feature to this app. I use JQuery , but it doesn't matter what javascript framework I use. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function callbackFunction(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
        $('document').ready(function(){

            $('#x').click(function() {
              $.post('/ajax_2/servlet',callbackFunction)

            });
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <a href="#" id="x">Increase it</a>
        <div id="content"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Servlet

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Integer myInteger = (Integer)session.getAttribute("myInteger");
    if(myInteger == null)
        myInteger = new Integer(0);
    else
        myInteger = new Integer(myInteger+1);
    session.setAttribute("myInteger", myInteger);
    response.getWriter().println(myInteger);
```

**The Question:**

I use **out.print** to transfer data from a servlet to javascript code (ajax code) , but If I have a complex structure such as a **Vector of Objects** or something like this , what is the best way to transfer the data? what about an **XML** file , **JSON** ? Is there any **special** jsp/servlets library to transfer data from a servlet to ajax application ? How can I parse this data in the **callbackFunction** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is using [JSON](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)). There are several Java libraries which can convert fullworthy Java objects to a JSON string and vice versa. Further JSON can be accessed in Javascript in a fully natural way without converting/massaging the data forth and back in another format.

As to the server side part, I strongly recommend to pick [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) as JSON serializer. Gson is the preferred choice since it supports converting complex Javabeans and arrays, collections and maps of them to JSON and vice versa without pains in a single line of code. It even supports generics. Basically all you need to do is the following:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(object);
```

Check the [user guide](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to learn more about the powers of Gson.

All with all, the following in the server side is sufficient:

```
public static void writeJson(HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(object));
}
```